# No Vertical Scrollbars in FF with SSRS Reportviewer

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportviewer2008

I'm using SSRS to render reports. In IE, SSRS renders a vertical scrollbar but in FireFox there is no vertical scrollbar. Does anyone know a fix? I need scrolling in both IE and FF.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptView" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" ForeColor="#000066" 
        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt"  
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Arial" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt"
        LinkActiveColor="#000066" LinkActiveHoverColor="Orange"
        BackColor="#DBDBDB" SplitterBackColor="#DBDBDB" 
        BorderColor="#000066" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
        ToolBarItemBorderStyle="None" ToolBarItemBorderColor="Orange" ToolBarItemHoverBackColor="#E0E0E0">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here to view the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnXXa.png) I would suggest to the changes in excel sheet. Please see the setting screen shot attached to activate the scroll bars in excel